# How do I create an account that can only use the ls and cd commands?

Tags: linux

How do I create an account on a CentOS box such that the user can only use the cd and ls commands but has full rights to use those commands everywhere on the filesystem? The user must be able to view the names of ALL files and directories on the system, but must not be able to view their contents, make any changes, etc.

Comment: This would be extremely difficult, if its possible at all.   It probably requires writing your own shell which only allows access to those commands and then using SELinux to enforce those limits.

Comment: Sounds like setting up an ftp server but restricting the allowable commands (e.g., no RETR) could work. How will the user be accessing the system? Via ssh from another system? Sitting at the console?

Comment: When you say "ALL files and directories on the system", are you including directories (e.g. in /proc and /var and users' .ssh directories) that are accessible only by root or the directories' owners and not by other normal users? If yes, that means the solution has to run as root. Not a show-stopper, just something we need to take into account when proposing a solution.

Comment: User must be able to SSH in and sit at the console.  Yes, the user will have to be root equivalent.

Comment: I think @davidgo is right, you need to write your own shell, which is very hard. The "need to be root equivalent" and "restrict to a mindnumbingly small list of constraints" are polar opposites. You rally need to think this through.

Answer (score 3):

You could so something crazy... like write a very dumb shell as a bash script. Then you can use that bash script as your shell for that user.

create a file called dumb_shell and stick this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "$(pwd)$ "
while read line
do
        command=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        # check if it is one of the valid commands
        if [ "$command" = "ls" -o "$command" = "cd" -o "$command" = "pwd" -o "$command" = "exit" ]
        then
                #check for possible security vulnerabilities in the command
                if [ "$(echo $line | awk '/;|>|<|&|\|/ {print}')" = "" ]
                then
                        #execute the command
                        $line
                fi
        fi
        printf "$(pwd)$ "
done
```

When I tested this, I placed the file in my /opt/ directory.
Make sure the file is executable

`chmod a+x /opt/dumb_shell`

Make dumb_shell the shell that is used when the user logs in. You can do that by replacing the shell for that user in the /etc/passwd file or using `usermod -s /opt/dumb_shell username`.

The entry in /etc/passwd should change as shown below:

```
user:x:1001:1001:user,,,:/home/user:/bin/bash
```

changed to:

```
user:x:1001:1001:user,,,:/home/user:/opt/dumb_shell
```

You will have to make sure that the user you choose has enough permissions to see all the files that you wish them to be able to see.

Comment: In order to be root, this would neet to replace the "1001" values with "0" to make it root.  Also, you need to ensure that the user can't exploit any other services on the system (like ftp for example).

Comment: @davidgo Good point. I didn't think about the other services that might use the same credentials. Unfortunately my answer does not account for all the possibilities and I don't know if any answer can. Pascal would have to try all the remote access services installed on the system (ftp, samba, scp,...) and lock them down as needed. Perhaps it would be better to just provide the user in question with a directory listing of the entire system rather than giving them any kind of access.